# sqlite query for retrieving data between two dates saved as strings

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

```
 NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ADDEXPENSE(date, description, category, amount) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\")", fieldOne.text, fieldTwo.text,fieldThree.text , fieldFour.text];
```

i have taken a date picker for the fieldOne and saving data is working fine.
but how to retreive the data between two dates?

and this is the the pickerview i used

```
UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;
NSDate *dateSelected = [picker date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this [Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) on [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) website. You can adapt those functions to retrieve unix-timestamp from format saved by **NSDate** and than simply use them in your SQL query in **WHERE** clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a sqlite query to select rows in a date range.  First you must format in sql friendly format like so:

```
NSDate * selected = [datePicker date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString * dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:selected];
NSString * sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM table WHERE (startdate <= '%@') AND (enddate >= '%@)", dateString, dateString];
```

and so forth.  You need to format your dates properly when inserting them into your table.

Answer (score 1):

I also stuck with same problem. I have to fetch data between two dates. but I am storing date as string in `SQLite` in `'YYYY-MM-dd'` this format. then i use below query to fetch data. & I got Result. In this I just typecast my date column to `Date` type.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnnName(Date) BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-dd' and 'YYYY-MM-dd'
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to retrieve the dates and convert into the nsdates.Then you have to check the each row date (whether it is between the two mentioned dates or not) using the compare function in dates.

Answer (score 0):

Following was regarding to an iOS App which I was doing, which uses SQLite DB.

```
SELECT COUNT(carSold) 
FROM cars_sales_tbl
WHERE date
BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
AND carType = "Hybrid"
```

It works like a charm!
Hope someone will get use out of it!

Cheers!